# idea and tomcat dont match the code and the execution path

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am using Idea 10.5.4 for Java development in my work. Currently I work on a Ubuntu 11.10 and using Java6 with Tomcat 7.

When I try to debug the application and move step by step, there is a problem: After a while, the code and the execution path starts to differ. So I could not trace a particular problem with the application.

I use Ant and when I start debugging from IDEA, IDEA makes the ant build and deploys the code to Tomcat. So there must be no difference between the code and classes on server.

What can be causing this difference? Some sort of optimization that should not be done on debug mode?

Thanks for any information in advance.

Comment: Do you have `debug=on` in your Ant `javac` task? Check that there is no stale copy of the code in a jar or classes directory deployed to the server.

Comment: i have debug=true and yes there are classes directory deployed on the server under the WEB-INF folder of the application. What should i do?

Comment: Does your Ant build modify sources or classes in any way, like bytecode instrumentation, aspects, annotations? What debug configuration type do you use? Do you use Remote debug or start Tomcat from IDEA? If deploying from Ant you should disable built-in IDEA deployment. Are you sure Tomcat hot swaps your changed classes?  Check that there is no other web application deployed with older copy of the same classes.

Comment: part of compile target : <target name="compile" depends="clear">

        <javac srcdir="${srcdir}" destdir="${builddir}" classpathref="classpath" source="1.6"
               target="1.6" debug="true" verbose="true">
            <compilerarg line="-encoding utf-8"/>
        </javac>

Comment: part of make target : <target name="make" depends="compile">

        <!--<war destfile="${distdir}/${warfile}" webxml="${basedir}/env/prod/web.xml">-->
         <war destfile="${distdir}/${warfile}" webxml="${webinfdir}/web.xml">
            <fileset dir="${webdir}"/>
            <classes dir="${builddir}"/>
            <classes dir="${srcdir}" includes="**/*.properties, **/*.xml, **/*.wsdl, **/*.vm, **/*.wsdd"/>

Comment: Please send a small sample project to reproduce this debugger problem to JetBrains support.